# Aggregating Data by Month, but first converting timezones - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, aggregate-functions

I have a database that records time in UTC. I need to convert this time to Local Time, and then aggregate the data by Month on this new Local Time that I have created. Everything works fine if I just aggregate on the original UTC Time, but of course, the value that I get at the end is slightly off which does not work for me. However, if I try to aggregate on Local Time, I just can't get it to work.

I am unable to use TIMESTAMP_LOCAL in my GROUP BY Clause, and neither am I able to use the whole YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), TIMESTAMP_UTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'). Same goes for the entire DATEFROMPARTS Function.

```
SELECT
       SUM([VALUE]) AS Required_Value
      ,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), TIMESTAMP_UTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time')), MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), TIMESTAMP_UTC AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time')), 1) AS TIMESTAMP_LOCAL

    FROM [DB].[TABLE]

    GROUP BY ???
```

Comment: While you can't use the alias `LOCAL_TIME` in the group by, you can just repeat the entire expression in the group by clause which will work, or alternatively use a subquery or cross apply to avoid repetition of the entire expression. [Examples on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tVPTGyGa)

Comment: @GarethD Thank you so much for explaining in so much detail, works perfectly and these approaches will stick to my mind now :)